# Angular2 - Display image

Tags: image, angular, typescript

I created a Angular2 app that allows the user to upload images. I want to implement a preview option. However, when i try to imperilment it the image doesn't show up. How do i achieve this feature?

UploadComponent.ts

```
import * as ng from '@angular/core';
//import { UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES } from 'ng2-uploader';
import {UploadService} from '../services/upload.service'; 

@ng.Component({
  selector: 'my-upload',
  providers:[UploadService], 
  template: require('./upload.html')
})
export class UploadComponent {
    progress:any; 
    logo:any; 
    filesToUpload: Array<File>;
    constructor(public us:UploadService){
        this.filesToUpload = [];
    }
    upload() {
        this.us.makeFileRequest("http://localhost:5000/api/SampleData/Upload", this.filesToUpload)
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
        }, (error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
    onFileChange(fileInput: any){
        this.logo = fileInput.target.files[0];
    }
}
```

Upload.html

```
<h2>Upload</h2>
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" placeholder="Upload image..." />
<button type="button" (click)="upload()">Upload</button>
 <img [src]="logo" alt="Preivew">
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way you try it, you don't get the image URL with `fileInput.target.files[0]`, but an object.

To get an image URL, you can use `FileReader` ([documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader))

```
onFileChange(fileInput: any){
    this.logo = fileInput.target.files[0];

    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
        this.logo = e.target.result;
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.target.files[0]);
}
```

Comment: Yup that explains why i kept seeing the fileReader on other peoples code. Thanks!

Comment: Can i leave change it to         reader.readAsDataURL(this.logo); instead of reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.target.files[0]); ? Or will this produce an error?

Answer (score 1):

```js
  
  filesToUpload: Array<File> = [];
  url: any;
  image: any;
  
//file change event 
  
  filechange(fileInput: any) {

    this.filesToUpload = <Array<File>>fileInput.target.files;
    this.image = fileInput.target.files[0]['name'];
    this.readurl_file(event);
  }
  
//read url of the file
  
  readurl_file(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (eve: any) => {
        this.url = eve.target.result;
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    }
  }
```

```html
  
   
   <div  class="form-group">
      <label for="image">Image</label>
      <input type="file"  class="form-control"  (change)="filechange($event)" placeholder="Upload file..." >
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <img [src]="url">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using FileReader is not a good practice. If an image is too large it can crash your browser because onload function load whole image in RAM.

Better approach is to use:

```
url = URL.createObjectURL($event.target.files[0]);
```

Then, show it out  with DomSanitizer:

```
this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url)
```

So in ts:

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {} 

onFileChange(fileInput: any){
    this.url = URL.createObjectURL($event.target.files[0]);
}

get previewUrl(): SafeUrl {
   return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.url);
}
```

And in html:

```
<img [src]="previewUrl"/>
```