# Angular2 Resize Input Image

Tags: angular, typescript, base64, filereader

I want to build a file upload (based on [Angular2 - Display image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933340/angular2-display-image)) with angular2 which uploads the original image but displays a resized image as a thumbnail preview.

*Before uploading* the image has to be displayed as a thumbnail below the file input field. Right now the image element is displaying a base64 string and all works fine... BUT!

```
getInput(fileInput) {

    const reader  = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = ((e: any) => {
        this.logo = e.target.result;
    });

    reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.target.files[0]);

}
```

If I want to change the image size by adding inline css with e.g. width 33px to the image element, the quality of the image is really bad:

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" (change)="getInput($event)" name="qr.logo"/>
<img [src]="logo" [width]="33" >
```

Is there a way to resize the image with angular without or with low quality loss?

Comment: no, you can't squeeze a big image in 33px and not suffer some quality loss.

Comment: you could use a canvas for better image processing options

Comment: yes as mentioned you can't really do much about the quality. I would recommend you however, to use the `svg` format if it's possible. Its quality and resolution scale extremely better with different sizes than other formats such `jpg` and `png`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular2-img-cropper package to resize the image.
https://github.com/cstefanache/angular2-img-cropper